# Buttons don't work anymore after upload build on itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app which is working normally when i install it on my iphone , but the problem is after i upload app on itunes , my favorite button from app is not working anymore .

Any idea what's wrong or if it's possible to make a debug for the build submited?

```
- (IBAction)fav:(id)sender {

    NSMutableArray *fav;
    NSMutableArray *imgFav;
    NSMutableArray *urlFav;

    BOOL alreadyInFav=NO;


    fav = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"radioName"]mutableCopy];
    imgFav = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"imgFav"]mutableCopy];
    urlFav = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"urlFav"]mutableCopy];

    for (int i=0; i<fav.count; i++) {
        if ([fav[i] isEqualToString:name[indexCell]]) {
            alreadyInFav=YES;
        }
    }


    if (alreadyInFav==NO) {

    if (fav) {

        NSString *nameCell=name[indexCell];
        [fav addObject:nameCell];
        NSString *imgCell=img[indexCell];
        [imgFav addObject:imgCell];
        NSString *urlCell=url[indexCell];
        [urlFav addObject:urlCell];
    }
    else
    {

        fav=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        imgFav=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        urlFav=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        NSString *nameCell=name[indexCell];
        [fav addObject:nameCell];
        NSString *imgCell=img[indexCell];
        [imgFav addObject:imgCell];
        NSString *urlCell=url[indexCell];
        [urlFav addObject:urlCell];
    }



    self.facImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_on.png"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:fav forKey:@"radioName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    favorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"radioName"]mutableCopy];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imgFav forKey:@"imgFav"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    imgFavorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"imgFav"]mutableCopy];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlFav forKey:@"urlFav"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    urlFavorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"urlFav"]mutableCopy];

    }



    else{


        favorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"radioName"]mutableCopy];
        imgFavorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"imgFav"]mutableCopy];
        urlFavorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"urlFav"]mutableCopy];
        NSString *urlCell;
        NSString *nameCell;
        NSString *imgCell;



        if (!fromFav) {

        urlCell=url[indexCell];
        nameCell=name[indexCell];
        imgCell=img[indexCell];


            [favorite removeObject:nameCell];
            [imgFavorite removeObject:imgCell];
            [urlFavorite removeObject:urlCell];}

        else{
            urlCell=url[cellColl];
            nameCell=name[cellColl];
            imgCell=img[cellColl];


            [favorite removeObjectAtIndex:cellColl];
            [imgFavorite removeObjectAtIndex:cellColl];
            [urlFavorite removeObjectAtIndex:cellColl];
        }




        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlFavorite forKey:@"urlFav"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imgFavorite forKey:@"imgFav"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favorite forKey:@"radioName"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        favorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"radioName"]mutableCopy];
        imgFavorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"imgFav"]mutableCopy];
        urlFavorite = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"urlFav"]mutableCopy];


        self.facImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite@3x.png"];





    }


    [self.collection reloadData];


}
```

Comment: If you could add code that shows your favorite button's functionality that would help. Are you using the same phone to test in Xcode and download from the App Store? Does the button work in the simulator?

Comment: i update my question. And yes . i am using the same phone